# sqlalchemy expression for selecting parent of parent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three classes in an ORM model with one to many relationship. How can I get the 'name' property of grandparent ('Role') using  hybrid_property in the grandchildren class ('Login')?

**Update:**
I use new property 'user'in 'column_list' of a flask-admin view.
I tried db.session instead of Sessions, it failed. I tried again Session() and it worked this time! I should have done something silly at first place.

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__  = 'roles'
    id       = db.Column(db.Integer(),  primary_key=True)
    name     = db.Column(db.String(50))
    users    = db.relationship('User')

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__  = 'users'
    id       = db.Column(db.Integer(),  primary_key=True)
    role_id  = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    role     = db.relationship("Role", back_populates="users")
    logins   = db.relationship('Login')

class Login(db.Model):
    __tablename__  = 'logins'
    id           = db.Column(db.Integer(),  primary_key=True)
    user_id      = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user         = db.relationship("User", back_populates="logins")

    @hybrid_property
    def user(self):
        return self.user.role.name

    @user.expression
    def user(cls):
         ???query = Session().query(Role.name).join(Role.users).filter(User.id==cls.user_id).label('user')
         return query
```

Comment: How are you using said property? On a quick glance it looks like you're creating a correlated scalar subquery just fine. Since you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, you could use the thread-local session `db.session` instead of creating one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated my question and actually my code worked this time!

Comment: Out of interest, how did using `db.session` fail?

Comment: I have seen elsewhere and I think on sqlalchemy's website too, that for 'expression' one cannot use db.session. The error is `No application found. Either work inside a view function or push`.

Comment: Ah true. Keep forgetting that the session provided by Flask-SQLA has some customizations in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question, it may help others. I found the problem and an easy workaround for it.
The reason for fail was to have the hybrid_property 'user' in flask-admin's 'column_searchable_list' of Login table View. I removed it from the list and the original code worked.